# How to make the text responsive to it size?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to make a website. However, the problem that I am getting is that when I minimize the browser, Yes, it is being responsive, but the text is going over the other components on the website and I am unsure how to work around this issue as I am quite stumped at this error.

Image for more clarification:
[Web error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bylI.png)

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- font awesome cdn link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jason.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">Revolutionary Fitness</div>
        <ul>
            <div class="items">
                <li><a href="HomePage.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="background">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h3>Classes</h3>
            <p>Insert Something Here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>Classes, coaches and community</h1>
        <div class="main text">
            <p>At Virgin Active, we do health and fitness differently. We have expertly crafted exercise experiences
                that are the perfect blend of intelligent programming and feel-good movement. We've got everything from
                Yoga to HIIT, so you can move your body any
                way you want.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="no.1" id="no.1">

        <div class="section">

            <img src="Yoga.jpg" alt="Yoga">

            <div class="ClassText">
                <h1>Yoga</h1>
                <p>
                    Choose from Classes with dynamism,energy and athleticism, to an authentic and peaceful experience.
                    <br><br>
                    Classes include: Align,Flow and Calm SkyPark Yoga
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="social">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="copyright">
            <small>&copy;2022 Revolutionary Fitness</small>
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Css:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;600&display=swap");
* {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background: #1b1b1b;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

nav .logo {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: cyan;
  box-shadow: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: top .3s;
}

.background {
  background-color: #212529;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  
  /* USE FLEXBOX */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  
  /* ADD SOME PADDING FOR BETTER UI */
  padding-inline: 16px; /* LEFT and Right */
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay h3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: crimson;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.overlay p {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.main h1 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  white-space: initial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.section {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.section img {
  height: 250px;
}

.section h1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: black;
}

.section p {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: initial;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 40px;
  clear: both;
}

.footer .social {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  color: #4b4c4d;
}

.footer .social a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #424242;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer .social a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.footer ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer .copyright {
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: use ```vw``` on font size. Something like ```font-size: 1.3vw;```

Comment: What do you want to happen? Should the text font-size get smaller so it's all guaranteed to fit (but be careful, it could get unreadably small) or should the text push the following content down to make room for itself, or should the text be cut off (maybe with ellipsis to show there is more)?

Comment: push the text down to make room for the test shld be the best option

Answer (score 0):

you can use css media query create responsive web page.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .overlay h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .overlay p {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .overlay h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .overlay p {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

Another way that is not recommended using viewport width and height

```
.overlay p {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
 }
```

Comment: why isn't viewport recommended?